# Establishing multiple https connections to a host using Spring Configurations

Tags: spring, web-services, tcp

I have set my ws config property as below.

```
connectionTimeOut=10000

readTimeOut=10000

maxConnectionsPerHost=5

maxTotalConnections=20

userName=XXXX

password=XXX

endpoint=https://example.com/XXX.svc
```

I had my ws context as below:

```
<property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
            <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${connectionTimeOut}" />
            <property name="readTimeout" value="${readTimeOut}"></property>
            <property name="maxConnectionsPerHost"><map><entry key="${endpoint}"  value="${maxConnectionsPerHost}"/></map></property>  
            <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="${maxTotalConnections}"/> 
            <property name = "credentials"> 
                <bean class = "org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials"> 
        <constructor-arg value = "${userName}"/>
        <constructor-arg value = "${password}"/>                       
                </bean> 
            </property>
        </bean>``
    </property>
```

When I enter the netstat command as below

```
netstat -n | grep <ip of XXX.com>
```

I need to get 5 TCP connections as ESTABLISHED.

For my above configurations I am always getting only 2 TCP connections as ESTABLISHED.

When I tried updating my endpoint as `http` instead `https`.I could see 5 TCP connections as ESTABLISHED. However the webservice response is not retrieved and getting an `WebServiceTransportException`.

Can any one please help me on getting this working.

Thank you in advance.